# Why do my AKS node have public IP even though "enableNodePublicIP" is set to false?

Tags: networking, azure, kubernetes, azure-networking, aks

I have an AKS cluster where I added a new node pool. While creating the node pool, I set the option "Enable public IP per node" as Disabled. However, I still notice that my nodes in the VMSS have a public IP. I am looking for a possible explanation of where does it come from?

**Additional Info:**

1. In the `kubectl get nodes -o wide`, I only see `INTERNAL-IP` and there's no `EXTERNAL-IP`.
2. When I try to make a connection with the node's public IP on port 443, it is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

It has been sometime, but have you found the cause?
If there is only one IP for all of your nodes then that might just be the outbound IP for your AKS cluster.